# List AND submit in the same view. How is it possible?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

Im currenty develoding a website using mvc 3 razor but have a little problem. I want to make a view that contains a submit form and a list. "Add product" and "List of products" should be in the same view. First I tought that partial views would be the solution but cant figure out how to make it work. Have no idea of how to pass a list of objects (products) to a partial view.
Someone has an idea of how to solve my problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MainView-Model:

```
public MainViewModel{

      public IList<Product> AvailableProducts{
           get; set;
      }
      public IList<Product> SelectedProducts{
           get; set;
      }
}
```

Mainview:

```
 @Html.RenderPartial("_SelectedProductsPartial", Model.SelectedProducts)
```

Partial View:

```
 @model IList<Product>
```

Controller:

```
 public ActionResult MainView(){

 MainViewModel model = new MainViewModel();
 model.AvailableProducts = ...;
 model.SelectedProducts = ...;

 return View(model);
```

Comment: Im a little unsure of how the setup is with the controller, model and view. Should I use the standard ProductsController, model and view? Have only been using mvc for the last couple of days and so far im used to one action per view. If I want to create a product i call the create method in the controller and use the create view. How can I make use of Create and List in the controller? Do i need to change the controller or should i make a completly new controller to handle the view? Im still a neewbie to mvc so Im affraid that i need a little more details :)

Comment: if you use RenderPartial you don't need a controller-methode for this.
just create the model in the MainView-methode in the controller.

Answer (score 1):

Partials are not required for what you are trying to accomplish, although they can be helpful for keeping your concerns separated.

To answer your question, you can pass an object to a strongly-typed partial view by passing it as the second argument, like so:

```
@Html.Partial("_MyPartialName", Model.ThingIWantToPass)
```

In this example this would be a strongly typed partial of the same type as `Model.ThingIWantToPass`.

Answer (score 0):

The displaying part

```
// In your action method
IList<ProductViewModel> productListViewModel = new List<ProductViewModel>();
return PartialView(productListViewModel);


//Your view model:


@model IEnumerable<YourNamespace.WebUI.Models.ProductViewModel>

@for(int i = 0; i < Model.Count(); i++){
   // Assuming your product has a name property
   @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Name);
}
```